# GIS is for GeoGRAPHIC information system. What about information systems for other geosciences?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

[Earthscience.SE](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com) is now in public beta, and there are questions on position of geoinformatic questions there, like [this one](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/77/101). It seems that there is not a consensus yet on this topic. For Geographic Information Systems, it is clear that they are on topic here (so they should be asked on Earthscience.SE only if focusing on the "earthscience" part). But what about software related to other earth sciences than geography - geology, stratigraphy, climatology etc. (some examples are in the linked earthscience.SE question)? Are all of them on topic on GIS.SE, or just some of them? If they are on topic here, is there any category of such software behind GIS that should be asked here rather than there?

Comment: Some questions on Earth Science should be on GIS.SE and vice-versa (weather related processes should be on Earth Science SE.) Example ES SE question that should be on GIS SE http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/756/info-for-land-cover-corine

Comment: @Mapperz: I have seen that question yesterday, and it made me start thinking about the borderline between ES.SE and GIS.SE.

Comment: We've had very similar discussions (GIS.SE vs *other*.SE) before. A good recent example is http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3569/are-questions-about-obtaining-geospatial-data-on-topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if a Question is on-topic here, it may be noticeably more on-topic (i.e. core business) for another SE site (e.g. [Earth Science SE](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/)). If that is the case, I think suggesting migration to that other site is reasonable.

Likewise, if we see a GIS (our core business) question on another site (e.g. [Earth Science SE](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/)) that we participate in (where it may appear noticeably more peripheral) then, on a case-by-case basis, I think that it is reasonable to suggest that it be migrated here.

If I see [ArcGIS Desktop (including ArcPy) questions on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arcgis?sort=newest&pageSize=15) I sometimes comment there that they be better asked here because I rarely migrate or seek migration nowadays. I think suggesting they delete and re-ask on the other site is a better practice. Also, questions over 30 days old cannot be migrated.

Comment: Now that Earth Science SE is out of "beta",  is this going to be more of a problem? Just searching for GIS on that site brings up things that should be over here. The GIS tag over there doesn't mention this site...

Comment: @Spacedman I think any impact is yet to be determined. I suspect suboptimal site choice for some questions will be ongoing and that there will continue to be some push-pull of questions between sites irrespective of whether Beta labeling has been removed.

Comment: At what point (or who do we have to ask) do we get an explicit "Migrate to *some other site*" option when voting to close a Q? I thought Stack Overflow had that, but I don't see it now... Or has that been zapped across the whole SE network?

Comment: @Spacedman I'd like to see it this way (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186461/215590).  Migration currently works as described at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249.  Since moderators can technically migrate anywhere the migration options provided to other GIS SE users are not visible to us.  If you want to ask a Meta GIS SE question about migration that will trigger us to look into whether we are able to modify that for our site or just get the network-wide options.